# AWS Cloud Formation Resource for the requesting user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a cloud formation template that I want to be run by multiple teams. I want to know which team is starting the stack using my template without making it a parameter.

Although I eventually want to use value in a map a simpler example as an Output will be easier to explain.

```
"Outputs":{
   "UserId" : {
    "Description" : "Group of user who called the stack",
    "OutputKey" : "GroupARN",
    "OutputValue" : { 
       "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "*** Resource of calling user ***", "AWS::IAM::Group"]
    }
  }
}
```

What I can't find is what resource I should use.

The guide for resources only talks about resources created in the template and that may mean I can't get the stack caller from a resource. If that is true is there another way or will I have to fall back to putting it as a parameter on the cloud formation template.

Ref:

- [Fn::GetAtt reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)
- [Resources section structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [pseudo parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html)? You can do something like:

```
...
"OutputValue" : {
    {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"}
}
```

> AWS::AccountId
>
> Returns the AWS account ID of the account in which the stack is being created, such as 123456789012.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen the docs on pseudo parameters, I think it is the Resource I wanted to query but as I suspected it doesn't contain a reference of the AWS IAM user calling the stack. I am going to mark as answer and make a feature request to AWS Support.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that currently my answer is as close as you can get. If they add this feature I think you should come back and update this page.